# iOS Concurrency - Not reaching anywhere's near theoretical maximum

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

I'm new to Grand Central Dispatch and have been running some tests with it doing some processing on an image. Basically I'm running a grayscale algorithm both sequentially and using GCD and comparing the results.

here is the basic loop:

```
UInt8 r,g,b;
uint pixelIndex;
for (uint y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (uint x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        pixelIndex = (uint)(y * width + x);

        if (pixelIndex+2 < width * height) {
            sourceDataPtr = &sourceData[pixelIndex];

            r = sourceDataPtr[0+0];
            g = sourceDataPtr[0+1];
            b = sourceDataPtr[0+2];

            int value = (r+g+b) / 3;
            if (value > MAX_COLOR_VALUE) {
                value = MAX_COLOR_VALUE;
            }

            targetData[pixelIndex] = value;
            self.imageData[pixelIndex] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

It simply runs through and takes the average value for Red, Green & Blue and uses that for the gray value. Very Simple. Now the parallel version basiclaly breaks the image into portions and then computes those portions seperately. Namely 2, 4, 8, 16 & 32 portions. I'm using the basic GCD so pass each portion in as it's own block to run concurrently. Here is the GCD wrapped code:

```
dispatch_group_t myTasks = dispatch_group_create();

for (int startX = 0; startX < width; startX += width/self.numHorizontalSegments) {
    for (int startY = 0; startY < height; startY += height/self.numVerticalSegments) {
        // For each segment, enqueue a block of code to compute it.
        dispatch_group_async(myTasks, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
             // grayscale code...
        });
    }
}
dispatch_group_wait(myTasks, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

Everything is working fine. But what I am not understanding is the speedup / CPU usage. Running tests in the simulator (which is using my dual core CPU) I am getting:

- ~0.0945s run time sequentially
- ~0.0675s run time using GCD

This is a speedup of around ~28% (a.k.a taking 72% the time of the sequential version). 
Theoretically, on a 2-core machine 100% speedup is the maximum. So this is falling well short of that and I can't figure out why.

I monitor the CPU usage and it maxes out around 118% - why is it not reaching closer to 200%? If anyone has an idea as to what I should change, or what is the culprit here I would greatly appreciate it.

My Theories:

- Not enough work on CPU (but image is ~3,150,000 pixels)
- Not enough time to fire up to near 200%? Maybe each thread requires a longer runtime before it starts chewing up that much of the CPU?
- I thought maybe the overhead was pretty high, but a test of launching 32 empty blocks to a queue (also in a group) took around ~0.0005s maximum.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely guess. In the single-threaded case, you are CPU bound.  In the multi-threaded case, you are memory bound.  In other words, the two cores are reading the data from DRAM at the maximum bus bandwidth. As a result, the cores end up idling waiting for more data to process.

You can test my theory by doing a true luminance calculation:

```
int value = floor( 0.299 * red + 0.587 * green + 0.114 * blue );
```

That calculation will yield gray scale values in the range from 0 to 255, given 8-bit rgb values.  It also gives the processors more work to do per pixel. If you change that line of code, the time for the single threaded case should increase somewhat. And, if I'm correct, then the multi-threaded case should show a better performance improvement, as a percentage of the single-threaded time.

---

I decided to run some benchmarks of my own, both on the simulator and on an iPad2.  The structure of my code was as follows.

**Single Threaded**

```
start = TimeStamp();

for ( y = 0; y < 2048; y++ )
    for ( x = 0; x < 1536; x++ )
        computePixel();

end = TimeStamp();
NSLog( @"single      = %8.3lf msec", (end - start) * 1e3 );
```

**Two Threads using GCD**

```
dispatch_group_t tasks = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0 );

start = TimeStamp();
dispatch_group_async( tasks, queue, 
^{
    topStart = TimeStamp();

    for ( y = 0; y < 1024; y++ )
        for ( x = 0; x < 1536; x++ )
            computePixel();

    topEnd = TimeStamp();
});

dispatch_group_async( tasks, queue, 
^{
    bottomStart = TimeStamp();

    for ( y = 1024; y < 2048; y++ )
        for ( x = 0; x < 1536; x++ )
            computePixel();

    bottomEnd = TimeStamp();
});

wait = TimeStamp();
dispatch_group_wait( tasks, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER );
end = TimeStamp();

NSLog( @"wait        = %8.3lf msec", (wait - start) * 1e3 );
NSLog( @"topStart    = %8.3lf msec", (topStart - start) * 1e3 );
NSLog( @"bottomStart = %8.3lf msec", (bottomStart - start) * 1e3 );
NSLog( @" " );
NSLog( @"topTime     = %8.3lf msec", (topEnd - topStart) * 1e3 );
NSLog( @"bottomeTime = %8.3lf msec", (bottomEnd - bottomStart) * 1e3 );
NSLog( @"overallTime = %8.3lf msec", (end - start) * 1e3 );
```

Here are my results.

**Running (r+g+b)/3 on the simulator**

```
2014-04-03 23:16:22.239 GcdTest[1406:c07] single      =   21.546 msec
2014-04-03 23:16:22.239 GcdTest[1406:c07]  
2014-04-03 23:16:25.388 GcdTest[1406:c07] wait        =    0.009 msec
2014-04-03 23:16:25.388 GcdTest[1406:c07] topStart    =    0.031 msec
2014-04-03 23:16:25.388 GcdTest[1406:c07] bottomStart =    0.057 msec
2014-04-03 23:16:25.389 GcdTest[1406:c07]  
2014-04-03 23:16:25.389 GcdTest[1406:c07] topTime     =   10.865 msec
2014-04-03 23:16:25.389 GcdTest[1406:c07] bottomeTime =   10.879 msec
2014-04-03 23:16:25.390 GcdTest[1406:c07] overallTime =   10.961 msec
```

**Running (.299r + .587g + .114b) on the simulator**

```
2014-04-03 23:17:27.984 GcdTest[1422:c07] single      =   55.738 msec
2014-04-03 23:17:27.985 GcdTest[1422:c07]  
2014-04-03 23:17:29.306 GcdTest[1422:c07] wait        =    0.008 msec
2014-04-03 23:17:29.307 GcdTest[1422:c07] topStart    =    0.054 msec
2014-04-03 23:17:29.307 GcdTest[1422:c07] bottomStart =    0.060 msec
2014-04-03 23:17:29.307 GcdTest[1422:c07]  
2014-04-03 23:17:29.308 GcdTest[1422:c07] topTime     =   28.881 msec
2014-04-03 23:17:29.308 GcdTest[1422:c07] bottomeTime =   29.330 msec
2014-04-03 23:17:29.308 GcdTest[1422:c07] overallTime =   29.446 msec
```

**Running (r+g+b)/3 on the iPad2**

```
2014-04-03 23:27:19.601 GcdTest[13032:907] single      =  298.799 msec
2014-04-03 23:27:19.602 GcdTest[13032:907]  
2014-04-03 23:27:20.536 GcdTest[13032:907] wait        =    0.060 msec
2014-04-03 23:27:20.537 GcdTest[13032:907] topStart    =    0.246 msec
2014-04-03 23:27:20.539 GcdTest[13032:907] bottomStart =    2.906 msec
2014-04-03 23:27:20.541 GcdTest[13032:907]  
2014-04-03 23:27:20.542 GcdTest[13032:907] topTime     =  149.596 msec
2014-04-03 23:27:20.544 GcdTest[13032:907] bottomeTime =  149.209 msec
2014-04-03 23:27:20.545 GcdTest[13032:907] overallTime =  152.164 msec
```

**Running (.299r + .587g + .114b) on the iPad2**

```
2014-04-03 23:30:29.618 GcdTest[13045:907] single      =  282.767 msec
2014-04-03 23:30:29.620 GcdTest[13045:907]  
2014-04-03 23:30:34.008 GcdTest[13045:907] wait        =    0.046 msec
2014-04-03 23:30:34.010 GcdTest[13045:907] topStart    =    0.270 msec
2014-04-03 23:30:34.011 GcdTest[13045:907] bottomStart =    3.043 msec
2014-04-03 23:30:34.013 GcdTest[13045:907]  
2014-04-03 23:30:34.014 GcdTest[13045:907] topTime     =  143.078 msec
2014-04-03 23:30:34.015 GcdTest[13045:907] bottomeTime =  143.249 msec
2014-04-03 23:30:34.017 GcdTest[13045:907] overallTime =  146.350 msec
```

**Running ((.299r + .587g + .114b) ^ 2.2) on the iPad2**

```
2014-04-03 23:41:28.959 GcdTest[13078:907] single      = 1258.818 msec
2014-04-03 23:41:28.961 GcdTest[13078:907]  
2014-04-03 23:41:30.768 GcdTest[13078:907] wait        =    0.048 msec
2014-04-03 23:41:30.769 GcdTest[13078:907] topStart    =    0.264 msec
2014-04-03 23:41:30.771 GcdTest[13078:907] bottomStart =    3.037 msec
2014-04-03 23:41:30.772 GcdTest[13078:907]  
2014-04-03 23:41:30.773 GcdTest[13078:907] topTime     =  635.952 msec
2014-04-03 23:41:30.775 GcdTest[13078:907] bottomeTime =  634.749 msec
2014-04-03 23:41:30.776 GcdTest[13078:907] overallTime =  637.829 msec
```

Comment: BTW, in my test, that was not enough to have any significant affect in the benefit of running calculations concurrently. In my benchmark, it bumped it from 21% gain by using concurrent operations to a 25% gain (but, obviously, those gains were completely wiped out from the slower algorithm). When I did a significantly more complicated calculation (a luminance calculation that did an exponential gamma adjustment, too), the performance gain from concurrent requests was more material 45%, but, again, the algorithm was almost 10x slower, so it again largely defeated the purpose of the exercise.

Comment: So, your benchmarks are not exhibiting Alex's original problem at all?

Comment: Nope, not at all.  So I have to wonder if he was doing something like printing results from the background threads. Note that my code captures time stamps in the threads, but only prints results at the end, after both threads have completed.

Comment: @Rob Another possibility is that there's a difference in the way the output is handled.  My code writes the grayscale data to a 2D array of uint8_t. His code writes to `targetData` and `self.imageData`, but doesn't really specify what those two entities are.

Comment: Your comments made me go back to my benchmark. I was doing a "soup-to-nuts" benchmark (retrieving `UIImage`, getting its `CGImage`, getting its pixel buffer, allocating output pixel buffer, doing the conversions, creation of output image provider, `CGImage`, and `UIImage`). And, in that scenario, the concurrent rendition took 79% as long as the serial rendition. When I isolated my benchmark to just the conversion portion, the concurrent rendition took 53% as long as the serial rendition (i.e. nearly twice as fast).

Comment: @Rob Ah yes, that's another good explanation.  The results of a multithreading test will definitely be skewed if there's a lot of single threaded overhead in the test.

Comment: Thank you for this discussion - I found I was doing the same thing; timing the entire method (i.e. including creating image buffers, setting up arrays, copying into new image buffers) so I replaced where I was doing my timing to get better accuracy. My Parallel algorithm is really getting ~71% the runtime of my sequential version. I cannot figure out how to mimic both of your near 50% results. I tried stripping away my dynamic division of the picture and just doing bottom/top halving like you have done but no real change. I'm still playing around with it

Comment: @user3386109 One thing I was wondering is about the TimeStamp() method you're using. I'm using NSDate to determine the run times, but I can't think that is causing any problems. I went to test TimeStamp() to be sure but it says it does not exist

Comment: @Alex Using `NSDate` will not be the source of your problem, but you can use `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()` (or, alternatively, `CACurrentMediaTime()`), and then you can subtract the end time from the start time to get the number of seconds elapsed.

Comment: @Alex As Rob mentioned, there are several different timestamp functions in iOS. I used the `CACurrentMediaTime()` function in my test code. It returns times in seconds, which makes the calculations easy.

Answer (score 2):

In my tests, I found that if I just focused on the concurrent B&W conversion, I achieved something close to the "twice the speed" that you were expecting (the parallel rendition took 53% as long as the serial rendition). When I also included the ancillary portions of the conversion (not only the conversion, but also the retrieval of the image, preparation of the output pixel buffer, and creation of the new image, etc.), then the resulting performance improvement was less spectacular, where elapsed time was 79% as long as the serial rendition.

In terms of why you might not achieve an absolute doubling of performance, even if you just focus on the portion that can enjoy concurrency, Apple attributes this behavior to the overhead in scheduling code for execution. In their discussion about using `dispatch_apply` in the [Performing Loop Iterations Concurrently](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW23) in the *Concurrency Programming Guide,* they contemplate the balance between the performance gain of concurrent tasks and the overhead that each dispatched block entails:

> You should make sure that your task code does a reasonable amount of work through each iteration. As with any block or function you dispatch to a queue, there is overhead to scheduling that code for execution. If each iteration of your loop performs only a small amount of work, the overhead of scheduling the code may outweigh the performance benefits you might achieve from dispatching it to a queue. If you find this is true during your testing, you can use striding to increase the amount of work performed during each loop iteration. With striding, you group together multiple iterations of your original loop into a single block and reduce the iteration count proportionately. For example, if you perform 100 iterations initially but decide to use a stride of 4, you now perform 4 loop iterations from each block and your iteration count is 25. For an example of how to implement striding, see “[Improving on Loop Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW2).”

As an aside, I think it might be worth considering creating your own concurrent queue and using `dispatch_apply`. It is designed for precisely this purpose, optimizing `for` loops that can enjoy concurrency.

---

Here is my code that I used for my benchmarking:

```
- (UIImage *)convertImage:(UIImage *)image algorithm:(NSString *)algorithm
{
    CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;
    NSAssert(imageRef, @"Unable to get CGImageRef");

    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGImageGetDataProvider(imageRef);
    NSAssert(provider, @"Unable to get provider");

    NSData *data = CFBridgingRelease(CGDataProviderCopyData(provider));
    NSAssert(data, @"Unable to copy image data");

    NSInteger       bitsPerComponent = CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef);
    NSInteger       bitsPerPixel     = CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(imageRef);
    CGBitmapInfo    bitmapInfo       = CGImageGetBitmapInfo(imageRef);
    NSInteger       bytesPerRow      = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef);
    NSInteger       width            = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    NSInteger       height           = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace       = CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef);

    void *outputBuffer = malloc(width * height * bitsPerPixel / 8);
    NSAssert(outputBuffer, @"Unable to allocate buffer");

    uint8_t *buffer = (uint8_t *)[data bytes];

    CFAbsoluteTime start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();

    if ([algorithm isEqualToString:kImageAlgorithmSimple]) {
        [self convertToBWSimpleFromBuffer:buffer toBuffer:outputBuffer width:width height:height];
    } else if ([algorithm isEqualToString:kImageAlgorithmDispatchApply]) {
        [self convertToBWConcurrentFromBuffer:buffer toBuffer:outputBuffer width:width height:height count:2];
    } else if ([algorithm isEqualToString:kImageAlgorithmDispatchApply4]) {
        [self convertToBWConcurrentFromBuffer:buffer toBuffer:outputBuffer width:width height:height count:4];
    } else if ([algorithm isEqualToString:kImageAlgorithmDispatchApply8]) {
        [self convertToBWConcurrentFromBuffer:buffer toBuffer:outputBuffer width:width height:height count:8];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@: %.2f", algorithm, CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start);

    CGDataProviderRef outputProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, outputBuffer, sizeof(outputBuffer), releaseData);

    CGImageRef outputImageRef = CGImageCreate(width,
                                              height,
                                              bitsPerComponent,
                                              bitsPerPixel,
                                              bytesPerRow,
                                              colorspace,
                                              bitmapInfo,
                                              outputProvider,
                                              NULL,
                                              NO,
                                              kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

    UIImage *outputImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:outputImageRef];

    CGImageRelease(outputImageRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(outputProvider);

    return outputImage;
}

/** Convert the image to B&W as a single (non-parallel) task.
 *
 * This assumes the pixel buffer is in RGBA, 8 bits per pixel format.
 *
 * @param inputButter  The input pixel buffer.
 * @param outputBuffer The output pixel buffer.
 * @param width        The image width in pixels.
 * @param height       The image height in pixels.
 */
- (void)convertToBWSimpleFromBuffer:(uint8_t *)inputBuffer toBuffer:(uint8_t *)outputBuffer width:(NSInteger)width height:(NSInteger)height
{
    for (NSInteger row = 0; row < height; row++) {

        for (NSInteger col = 0; col < width; col++) {

            NSUInteger offset = (col + row * width) * 4;
            uint8_t *rgba = inputBuffer + offset;

            uint8_t red   = rgba[0];
            uint8_t green = rgba[1];
            uint8_t blue  = rgba[2];
            uint8_t alpha = rgba[3];

            uint8_t gray = 0.2126 * red + 0.7152 * green + 0.0722 * blue;

            outputBuffer[offset]     = gray;
            outputBuffer[offset + 1] = gray;
            outputBuffer[offset + 2] = gray;
            outputBuffer[offset + 3] = alpha;
        }
    }
}

/** Convert the image to B&W, using GCD to split the conversion into several concurrent GCD tasks.
 *
 * This assumes the pixel buffer is in RGBA, 8 bits per pixel format.
 *
 * @param inputButter  The input pixel buffer.
 * @param outputBuffer The output pixel buffer.
 * @param width        The image width in pixels.
 * @param height       The image height in pixels.
 * @param count        How many GCD tasks should the conversion be split into.
 */
- (void)convertToBWConcurrentFromBuffer:(uint8_t *)inputBuffer toBuffer:(uint8_t *)outputBuffer width:(NSInteger)width height:(NSInteger)height count:(NSInteger)count
{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.domain.app", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
    NSInteger stride = height / count;

    dispatch_apply(height / stride, queue, ^(size_t idx) {

        size_t j = idx * stride;
        size_t j_stop = MIN(j + stride, height);

        for (NSInteger row = j; row < j_stop; row++) {

            for (NSInteger col = 0; col < width; col++) {

                NSUInteger offset = (col + row * width) * 4;
                uint8_t *rgba = inputBuffer + offset;

                uint8_t red   = rgba[0];
                uint8_t green = rgba[1];
                uint8_t blue  = rgba[2];
                uint8_t alpha = rgba[3];

                uint8_t gray = 0.2126 * red + 0.7152 * green + 0.0722 * blue;

                outputBuffer[offset]     = gray;
                outputBuffer[offset + 1] = gray;
                outputBuffer[offset + 2] = gray;
                outputBuffer[offset + 3] = alpha;
            }
        }
    });

    return YES;
}

void releaseData(void *info, const void *data, size_t size)
{
    free((void *)data);
}
```

On an iPhone 5, this took 2.24 seconds to convert a 7360 × 4912 image with the simple, serial method, and took 1.18 seconds when I used `dispatch_apply` with two loops. When I tried 4 or 8 `dispatch_apply` loops, I saw no further performance gain.