# Multithreaded Image Processing slower than Single Thread?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, image-processing, grand-central-dispatch

I'm processing an image in Objective-C and tried out Grand Central Dispatch, the results were terrible. CPU usage doubled and the time to process the image doubled.

```
- (void) processImage:(struct ImageData)image {
    imageData = image;

    [allyMinionManager prepareForPixelProcessing];

    int cores = 4;
    int section = imageData.imageHeight/cores;
    if (section < 1) {
        section = 1;
    }
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    for (int i = 0; i < cores; i++) {
        int yStart = section * i;
        int yEnd = yStart + section;
        if (i == cores - 1) {
            yEnd = imageData.imageHeight;
        }
        dispatch_group_enter(group);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
            for (int y = yStart; y < yEnd; y++) {
                uint8_t *pixel = imageData.imageData + (y * imageData.imageWidth)*4;
                for (int x = 0; x < imageData.imageWidth; x++) {
                    [allyMinionManager processPixel:pixel x:x y:y];

                    pixel += 4;
                }

            }
            dispatch_group_leave(group);
        });
    }
    dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    [allyMinionManager postPixelProcessing:imageData];
}
```

I separate the image between the cores, then wait for the dispatched tasks to finish. Each thread should process 240,000 pixels if I have a 1200x800 image.

Core set to 1: 95% CPU usage, 16ms processing time

Core set to 4: 120% CPU usage, 33ms processing time

Any idea why the performance is so bad?

(Bonus question: When I set compiler optimization flag to lowest, my CPU usage goes from 45% to 300% in my program. Is that normal?)

Comment: I switched to dispatch_apply, seems to be lots better than my previous method. Though my CPU usage goes up by 10% with 2 cores, goes up by 50% with 4 or more cores.

I haven't tested the processing speed because it happens too fast, I have the processing running at a constant 60fps. I'll keep it multithreaded just in-case my processing becomes too intensive and 1 core runs slower than 60fps.

I would mark your comment as an answer if you pasted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have often found that using multithreaded code often doesn't achieve the benefit one would theoretically expect. There are diminishing returns. See [iOS Concurrency - Not reaching anywhere's near theoretical maximum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22850936/1271826) for a fuller discussion.

Note, you could use `dispatch_group_async` and that would eliminate the need to manually enter and leave the group (you only need to do that if the blocks of code you are dispatching are, themselves, asynchronous). Even better, given that you are waiting at the end, you should consider using `dispatch_apply`, which eliminates the group altogether.

Using `dispatch_apply`, running on a Mac I found 2 threads took 78% of the elapsed time of single threaded implementation, 4 took 47% of the time, and 8 took 38% of the time. So there were benefits stemming from the increase in the number of threads, but they were of diminishing returns.

On an iPhone 6+, I experienced similar performance improvement when I went from one to two threads, but I realized no further performance improvement beyond that as I went to four or eight threads.

So, bottom line, I'd suggest trying `dispatch_apply`. And don't be surprised if the performance improvement levels off rather quickly on the device. So try using only 2 "cores" and see what the results are.